# asp.net-mvc-6 active menu item by page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

```
<a asp-action="Index" class="active" asp-controller="User">blah</a>
<a asp-action="tarif" asp-controller="Home">blah</a>
<a asp-action="Account" asp-controller="Home">blah</a>
```

With new asp-helpers I cant insert *@if () < text> class="active" < / text>* in a tag .

How do I make it correctly and easier?

I know there are a lot of solutions, but I want to know -  how to solve it correctly in new asp.

Answer (score 3):

To use a complete statement inside an element, you need to wrap it with `{}`.

```
<a asp-action="Index" @{ if (isActive) { <text> class="active" </text> } } asp-controller="User">blah</a>
```

To use an expression when it isn't detecting the end properly, you'll want to wrap it with `()`.

```
<a asp-action="Index" class="@((isActive) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="User">blah</a>
```

Comment: But "The tag helper 'a' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area." error.

Comment: Hmm, I was unaware they blocked that - it makes sense, though, and would be good practice. You should probably be using something closer to the 2nd then, or make a custom tag helper.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use Twitter "Bootstrap Wizard Plugin"it will help you with form wizard steps. Here is a url to "Bootstrap Wizard Plugin" :the http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/